# pandas Dataframe Replace NaN values with with previous value based on a key column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pd.dataframe that looks like this:

```
key_value    a    b    c    d    e
value_01     1    10   x   NaN  NaN
value_01    NaN   12  NaN  NaN  NaN
value_01    NaN   7   NaN  NaN  NaN
value_02     7    4    y   NaN  NaN 
value_02    NaN   5   NaN  NaN  NaN
value_02    NaN   6   NaN  NaN  NaN
value_03     19   15   z   NaN  NaN
```

So now based on the key_value,

For column 'a' & 'c', I want to copy over the last cell's value from the same column 'a' & 'c' based off of the key_value.

For another column 'd', I want to copy over the row 'i - 1' cell value from column 'b' to column 'd' i'th cell.

Lastly, for column 'e' I want to copy over the sum of 'i - 1' cell's from column 'b' to column 'e' i'th cell .

**For every key_value** the columns 'a', 'b' & 'c' have some value in their first  row, based on which the next values are being copied over or for different columns the values are being generated for.

```
key_value    a    b    c    d    e
value_01     1    10   x   NaN  NaN
value_01     1    12   x    10   10
value_01     1    7    x    12   22
value_02     7    4    y   NaN  NaN
value_02     7    5    y    4    4
value_02     7    6    y    5    9
value_03     8    15   z   NaN  NaN
```

My current approach:

```
size = df.key_value.size
for i in range(size):
    if pd.isna(df.a[i]) and df.key_value[i] == output.key_value[i - 1]:
        df.a[i] = df.a[i - 1]
        df.c[i] = df.c[i - 1]
        df.d[i] = df.b[i - 1]
        df.e[i] = df.e[i] + df.b[i - 1]
```

For columns like 'a' and 'b' the ***NaN*** values are all in the same row indexes.

My approach works but takes very long since my datframe has over 50000 records, I was wondering if there is a different way to do this, since I have multiple columns like 'a' & 'b' where values need to be copied over based on 'key_value' and some columns where the values are being computed using say a column like 'b'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `pd.concat` with `groupby` and `assign`

```
pd.concat([
    g.ffill().assign(d=lambda d: d.b.shift(), e=lambda d: d.d.cumsum())
    for _, g in df.groupby('key_value')
])

  key_value     a  b  c    d    e
0  value_01   1.0  1  x  NaN  NaN
1  value_01   1.0  2  x  1.0  1.0
2  value_01   1.0  3  x  2.0  3.0
3  value_02   7.0  4  y  NaN  NaN
4  value_02   7.0  5  y  4.0  4.0
5  value_02   7.0  6  y  5.0  9.0
6  value_03  19.0  7  z  NaN  NaN
```

---

### `groupby` and `apply`

```
def h(g):
    return g.ffill().assign(
        d=lambda d: d.b.shift(), e=lambda d: d.d.cumsum())

df.groupby('key_value', as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(h)
```

Comment: I had made an error in the question where column 'd' and 'e were also supposed to adjusted based on the key_value. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I forgot to ask about 1 column say column 'f', where I just need to +1 from the previous cell value, how should I do that. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: adding one from previous cell value of which column?

Comment: It's a different column that I forgot to ask about in the original question, it would still be dependent on key value. So if the first value is 1, then the next cell in the same column should have 2, the one after that a 3. It's like ffill() but with +1.

Comment: So a column named `f` that refers to itself?  You see my question?  If the cell value of column f at i == 3 is supposed to be 1 plus the cell value of column f at i == 2?

Comment: In that case, include this to the `assign` `f=lambda d: d.f.shift() + 1`

Comment: So as I understand the `def h(g):` is currently performing ffill() on all columns other than the ones specified in `assign`, how can I exclude some columns from having anything done on them.

Comment: It keep giving me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at `g.[[` on the square brackets

Comment: That was a typo `g[['a', 'c']].ffill().assign(d=g.b.shift(), e=lambda d: d.d.cumsum())`

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but for the column `f` where I need to increment each cell's value by `+1`, I used `f=lambda d: d.f.shift() + 1` as you had mentioned but that just takes the last non empty cell and fills all the following cells with the value of the last 'non NaN cell value' + 1. I want to keep adding 1 for every cell until the `key_value` ends.

Comment: IIUC: `f=lambda d: d.f.iloc[0] + np.arange(len(d))` If that doesn't work, consider asking a new question where you have the latitude to clearly state what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` + `ffill` for the groupwise filling. The other operations require `shift` and `cumsum`.

In general, note that many common operations have been implemented efficiently in Pandas.

```
g = df.groupby('key_value')

df['a'] = g['a'].ffill()
df['c'] = g['c'].ffill()
df['d'] = df['b'].shift()
df['e'] = df['d'].cumsum()

print(df)

  key_value     a  b  c    d     e
0  value_01   1.0  1  x  NaN   NaN
1  value_01   1.0  2  x  1.0   1.0
2  value_01   1.0  3  x  2.0   3.0
3  value_02   7.0  4  y  3.0   6.0
4  value_02   7.0  5  y  4.0  10.0
5  value_02   7.0  6  y  5.0  15.0
6  value_03  19.0  7  z  6.0  21.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, that helps a lot, I had made an error in the question where column 'd' and 'e were also supposed to adjusted based on the key_value.

Comment: I just changed the df to g for them and it works. Just need to verify now. Thanks again.

Comment: I forgot to ask about 1 column say column `f`, where I just need to `+1` from the previous cell value, the column `f` is referring to itself, so if in column `f` at `i==1` the values is `1` the value in `i==2` should become to be `2` which was previously NaN